# How do I distinguish SSH logins from each other under the same user name?

Tags: ssh

I'm getting confused by the SSH sessions which are logged in from different places under the same user name. Is it possible to distinguish them somehow? For example, can I configure to annotate the remote IP address in the process table at the ← mark?

```
root       /usr/sbin/sshd -o PidFile=/var/run/sshd.init.pid
root         sshd: user [priv] ←
user          sshd: user
root         sshd: user [priv] ←
user          sshd: user@pts/3
user            -bash
user              /bin/ps -AH -o user,cmd
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give a better example as to why you're needing this?  My first reaction was to wonder if you're trying to distinguish between multiple individuals using the same account - which should not be generally allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w -f` shows the remote addresses, but also the tty names. For my situation, this is preferable over netstat/ss because I can match the sessions much more quickly with the process list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `netstat -p` or `ss -p` to match connection IP/ports with process ids; `netstat` shows just the `sshd: user [priv]` process, `ss` shows both of them.